# SwiftUI - Why does this picker's value become "x – 2"?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following picker to choose how often an event should recur:

```
struct RecurrenceSelector: View {   
@State var interval = 1

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Every", selection: $interval) {
                        Text("1 week").tag(1)
                        ForEach(2 ..< 1000) { weeks in
                            Text("\(weeks) weeks")
                                .tag(weeks)
                        }
                        }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    .onDisappear(perform: updateRruleString)
    }

private func updateRruleString() {
        print("INTERVAL: \(self.interval)")
    }
}
```

When I close the view, if I've set the Picker to 5 weeks, it'll print INTERVAL: 3. If I set it to 20 weeks, it'll print INTERVAL: 18.

I can't figure out why the value is getting deducted by two.

(I've shortened the code for brevity, but when I comment out all the other code, it behaves the same way).[image: Here's what it looks like (it looks as I expect)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Replace `ForEach(2 ..< 1000)` with `ForEach(2 ..< 1000, id: \.self)`

#### Explanation

ForEach has [several initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach). You are using

```
init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
```

In this case, the selection `interval` corresponds to the *index* you have selected; since your range starts at 2, and the index starts at 0, your selection `interval` will always be off by two.

If you use the initializer with the `id` parameter,

```
init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

then your selection corresponds to the *element*, not the index. Thus, your `interval` property will correspond to the displayed value.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the explanation (makes sense!). Your solution works perfectly.